# Are there real logs anywhere for S3 AccessDenied?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

Using the serverless framework.  I am doing some image processing in lambda with python and put the result in S3 bucket to be publicly accessible via a URL.

I spent hours and read every stack overflow answer, example code, etc that I could find to show how this is done.  But no dice.  I simply can't create minimum permissions that work.  For this python code:

```
with open("/tmp/" + filename, "rb") as f:
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, bucket_name, filename)
```

It works fine with this big hammer for permissions:

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: 'Allow'
  Action:
    - 's3:*'
  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*"
```

But I can't get it working with laser focused minimal permissions:

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: 'Allow'
  Action:
    - 's3:PutObject'
    - 's3:PutObjectAcl'
    - 's3:GetObject'
    - 's3:GetObjectAcl'
  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::mah-bucket/*"
- Effect: 'Allow'
  Action:
    - 's3:ListBucket'
  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::mah-bucket"
```

The stack trace is unhelpful.  AccessDenied and not much else.  There don't seem to be helpful logs anywhere.  Is there something obvious I am doing wrong, or someplace I could see good information about the write failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these days `iamRoleStatements:` are deprecated instead use I am [docs for reference](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/)

example fine grained policies for writing to bucket which needs `listing and put permission`

```
iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "s3:ListBucket"
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ""
              - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                - "bucket-name"
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "s3:PutObject"
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ""
              - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                - "bucket name"
                - "/*"
```

without join

```
provider:
    iam:
     role:
      statements:
       - Effect: "Allow"
         Action:
          - "s3:ListBucket"
         Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
       -  Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
           - "s3:PutObject"
          Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::buket-name/*"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There is so much old / deprecated code out there I had not looked at the docs in a while.  So many bleeding edges.  Your example caused serverless to crash on SLS deploy.  I updated from whatever I installed ~2 weeks ago to 2.39 and it identified a spacing issue.  Ironically, the example on the page you linked worked right away and demonstrated the use of the REF feature.  Thanks again.

Comment: glad to help you :)